# Jquery - how to highlight parent or grandparent li of an active menu child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery. I have a menu with 3 levels and I would like to hightlight parent or /and granparent of an active child item menu. I have the following code, but this is just highlighting the current active child, parent or grandparent.

How can I highlight the parent or/and granparent of any active child menu item?

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.sf-menu li a').each(function(index) {
         if((this.pathname.trim() == window.location.pathname))
             $(this).parent().addClass("selected1");
     });
});
```

My css:

```
.PageMenu .sf-menu li.selected1 > a {
    background-color: #565656;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/cprpvru1/14/ but its not working correctly